# Extracting information from a differential equation if the zero eigenvalue eigen-function is known

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, eigenvalues

Given the second order linear homogeneous differential equation
$$
-\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi_m(x) + V(x)\psi_m(x)=E_m\psi_m(x)
$$
with eigen-functions $\psi_m(x)$ and eigenvalues $E_m$, what information about the eigenvalue spectrum can be extracted if we know the eigenfunction of the zero eigenvalue?

A common occurrence with many second order linear homogeneous differential equations that cannot be solved analytically for all eigenvalues, is one can find the eigenfunction of the zero eigenvalue.
$$
-\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi_0(x) + V(x)\psi_0(x)=0
$$
My gut tells me their should be away to extract more information, but I do not know of such a method.

The eigenvalues depend on the boundary conditions imposed on the eigen-functions. For example: $\psi_m(0)=\psi_m(1)=0$ or $\psi_m(1)=\psi_m(\infty)=0$.

One possible method is to solve for the ladder operators for $V(x)$ and its pair $\tilde{V}$. For example
$$
A_{\pm} = \pm \dfrac{d}{dx}+W(x)
$$
and
\begin{align}
A_{+}A_{-} = -\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x)
&&
A_{-}A_{+} = -\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} + \tilde V(x)
\end{align}
But this depends on knowing the lowest eigen-function, not the zero eigen-function.

The potential has the following limits: $V(x=\pm \infty)=0$.

Comment: The question is rather vague in this form (also, what about boundary conditions?). If you are asking if it is *in principle* possible to find the eigenvalues, given $\psi_0$, the answer is of course yes because you can recover $V$ as $V=\psi''/\psi$.

Comment: If you can indeed factorize your ODE as described, then knowledge of any eigenfunction will be enough to construct the spectrum.  You have ladder operators, so you'll need to step up *and* down to get the full spectrum.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that, a priori, the zero eigenvalue $E=0$ is not distinguished in anyway by the form of the equation, without further conditions on $V(x)$. That's because it is always possible to shift all eigenvalues by $\delta E$ by shifting the potential $V(x) \to V(x) + \delta E$. However, for instance, if you require $V(x) \to 0$ at infinity, the such shifts are no longer allowed and the notion the $E=0$ eigenfunction may have some special properties with respect to the equation. Of course, such a condition could be very different from what *you* have in mind.

Comment: well, you know that the other eigenfunctions are orthogonal to the one you've found; hoping for more seems like asking what you can tell about a unitary matrix if all you know is one column.